# What does the lack of a Will defense mean?

Tags: dnd-4e, defense

There's a module which features an inanimate object without a Will defense.

Does a lack of Will defense mean you can't attack the target with a power that goes against Will? Or you can but it automatically misses? Or you can but it automatically does no damage?

I'd prefer RAW. However, how should a DM handle this if a player does attempt an attack?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rules Compendium p 176:

Object Immunities, Resistances, Vulnerabilities

> Unless otherwise noted, an object has immunity to the following: necrotic damage, poison damage, psychic damage, and any attack that targets Will.

That should give you your RAW answer. This is not universal, but when an object does not have a Will noted it is immune to attacks against Will.

Comment: Isn't the "1 always misses" rule still technically an optional rule in 4.0?

Comment: @Zibbobz not that I know of. Also note the  complete reversal in answer.

Comment: @Zibbobz "If your attack roll is lower than the defense score, the attack misses. Usually, there’s no effect. Some powers have an effect on a miss, such as dealing half damage.

Automatic Miss: If you roll a natural 1 (the die shows a 1), your attack automatically misses." - Miss, Rules Compendium

Answer (score 13):

> how should a DM handle this if a player does attempt an attack?

"The Bard attempts to destroy the iron bars of your prison, casting Vicious Mockery. The iron bars show no sign of being shamed, or in fact any other emotional response, and remain unflinchingly solid."

There would be no problem in the game as such if that were not the case in the rules system (a few hard-to-imagine Martial powers aside, such as a Rogue "outwitting" a door), but Psychic damage and powers that target Will have other benefits - generally these are good choices against a wider variety of monsters, compared to powers that e.g. target Fortitude or that do Lightning damage. So it isn't unfair on those players based on Will attacks, that their characters' powers cannot be used to damage objects.

Comment: The bars had a will of steel, as well as an everything else of steel.